# Python pandas shift dataframe with time index value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am quite new with python and am struggling with the `shift` in pandas.

I am comparing data, but it needs to be aligned to compare it. To align the data, I only need to shift one of the data's index values.

```
Reference data:                        Data to be shifted:
                          acc                                   acc
index                                  index            
1480681219**96**0000000     1          1480681220**04**0000000    8
1480681220**00**0000000     2          1480681220**08**0000000    9    
1480681220**04**0000000     3          1480681220**12**0000000    7
1480681220**08**0000000     4          1480681220**16**0000000   10
1480681220**12**0000000     5          1480681220**20**0000000    6
```

(The bold editing option did not seem to work, but I wanted to highlight those parts of the indexes)

I would like to shift my data frame with amount of extra time given. Please note, the time is in nanoseconds. I realized that something like `df.shift(2)` shifts my data 2 places, but I would like to shift my data with -80000000 nanoseconds which in this case is 2 places:

Input:

```
                     acc
index                   
1480681220040000000    8
1480681220080000000    9
1480681220120000000    7
1480681220160000000   10
1480681220200000000    6
```

Desired output:

```
                      acc
index          
1480681219960000000     8
1480681220000000000     9          
1480681220040000000     7
1480681220080000000    10
1480681220120000000     6
1480681220160000000   NaN
1480681220200000000   NaN
```

This is a smaller scale of my code:

```
class device_data(object):
    def __init__(self):

        _index = [1480681220040000000,
                 1480681220080000000,
                 1480681220120000000,
                 1480681220160000000,
                 1480681220200000000]

        self.df = pd.DataFrame({'acc': [8, 9, 7, 10, 6], 'index': _index})
        self.df = self.df.set_index('index')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    extratime = np.int64(-40000000)

    session = dict()
    session[2] = {'testnumber': '401',
              'devicename': 'peanut'}
    session[2]['data_in_device_class'] = device_data()

    print session[2]['data_in_device_class'].df

    if hasattr(session[2]['data_in_device_class'], 'df'):
        session[2]['data_in_device_class'].df = session[2]['data_in_device_class'].df.shift(int(round(extratime)))
    else:
        pass

    print session[2]['data_in_device_class'].df
```

When I ran the original code, it gave me this error:  `OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long`

I used `extratime = np.int64(extratime)` to solve the problem. I notice that with the scaled down version of my code, that it is not really needed.

My question still stands as how I could use shift to move my index with a value amount and not with the amount of places it needs to move?

Thank you

Comment: If you're planning to shift the entire df, you'd be better off `shift`ing the index and then `reindex` or `np.roll(df.index, some_value)` and use the returning array to `reindex`

Comment: When you say shift up or down, are you expecting `NaN` at top or bottom after shifting or you want a truncated df?

Comment: @EdChum: I have realized that I have asked the wrong question, as both your answers were helpful, it was not what what I wanted to accomplish. I feel embarrassed to say I need to rewrite the whole question. I realized, I  actually want to use shift to only shift the acc, but I would like to shift the value with the 'exstra time'. I will edit my question so that it also indicates what I am looking for

Comment: It generally helps to post the desired result to avoid ambiguity

Comment: @piRSquared: I have realized that I have asked the wrong question, as both your answers were helpful, it was not what what I wanted to accomplish. I feel embarrassed to say I need to rewrite the whole question. I realized, I actually want to use shift to only shift the acc, but I would like to shift the value with the 'exstra time'. I will edit my question so that it also indicates what I am looking for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you want to shift your index by the desired amount, and then `reindex`, to make things easier I take a `copy` here, shift the index, and we `reindex` on the `union` of the shifted index and the original index to introduce `NaN` rows:

```
In [232]:
df1 = df.copy()
df1.index -= 80000000
df1.reindex(df1.index.union(df.index))

Out[232]:
                      acc
index                    
1480681219960000000   8.0
1480681220000000000   9.0
1480681220040000000   7.0
1480681220080000000  10.0
1480681220120000000   6.0
1480681220160000000   NaN
1480681220200000000   NaN
```

Comment: Am I off base here?

Comment: @piRSquared I actually don't fully understand if the OP simply wants to add some scalar value to the index like in your answer, `shift` the df up/down with/without `NaN` so I commented to the OP, possibly your answer is what they really want

Comment: I guess we'll see :-)

Comment: @EdChum I edited the question now, and thus your answer no longer fits the question. Would you maybe mind removing it? Maybe I should have just deleted this whole question and started anew...

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:
You can just reassign your index with itself added to extra time.

Consider the dataframe `df` as an example

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(100).reshape(5, -1))
df
```

[image]

I can "shift" the entire dataframe down like this

```
df.index = df.index + 5
df
```

[image]

---

Let me know if this is on the mark.  Otherwise, I'll delete it.

Comment: I have realized that I have asked the wrong question, as both your answers were helpful, it was not what what I wanted to accomplish. I feel embarrassed to say I needed to rewrite the whole question. I realized, I actually want to use shift to only shift the acc, but I would like to shift the value with the 'extra time'. I edited the question now, and thus your answer no longer fits the question. Would you maybe mind removing it? Maybe I should have just deleted this whole question and started anew...

Comment: @Annemie27 I'd copy what you have and start a new question. Leave the old one here. You can, or I will roll back these edits after you've started new question. This way, even if slightly confusing, the two answers might help others who search and find your question. And you also get another question

Comment: @ piRSquared I think I'll have to rewrite the old question and put a link to that question here, then you can maybe post this answer there again? Because my new edited question was answered.